# Page OnLoad still happening even after redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I am limiting access to some pages until other pages have been visited. Visit Page A. If some process on Page A is not complete, when you try and go to Page B, you are redirected back to Page A. The redirect works, but OnLoad still gets run on Page B, even if the redirect occurs. I tried putting the redirect in OnInit of Page B, but PageB.OnLoad still gets run. How do I prevent OnLoad from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [overloaded version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Response.Redirect`. Passing `true` tells it not to continue executing the current method after the redirect.

However, you'll see a note on that page recommending you don't do this unless you have to. You'll need to judge the significance of what they say in your particular app.

As an alternative, consider adding a conditional code block in your load event hander:

```
if (isIncompletedPageA)
{
  Response.Redirect(urlToPageB)
}
else
{
  //normal page load code
}
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up going with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the answer because it was conceptually correct, and I did not specify what I am about to say in the question, but for further clarification:

I am using RedirectToRoute which does not have that optional parameter (at least in .Net 4), so I had to do:

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("myRouteName");
Response.End();
```